# Is there a way to auto-promote `vector<int>` to `vector<double>` during function invocation using C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I define a function which takes a `double`, I can generally call it with an `int` and get correct behavior.

```
double square(double d) {
    return d * d;
}

square(1); // valid call
```

However, if I have a function that takes `vector<double>`, it is not valid to call it with `vector<int>`

```
double sum(const vector<double>& d) {         
    double s = 0;                      
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++) 
        s += d[i];                     
    return s;                          
}

vector<int> f(1,5); 
sum(f); // Compiler error
```

One solution to this would be to use templates:

```
template<typename T>                    
double tsum(const vector<T>& d) {              
    double s = 0;                       
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)  
        s += d[i];                      
    return s;                           
}                                       
vector<int> f(1,5);
tsum<int>(f);  // Valid
```

However, in this case, we have to specify the type as part of the function, which is a little clunky, especially if I want to define a `dot` product function which can do the dot products of arbitrary combinations of numeric types, such `vector<int>` and `vector<double>` and `vector<float>`, because now every time this function is called, the caller has to explicitly specify which vector is which particular numeric type.

Is there some way to define a function, either using traditional or new `c++`, such that calls like
 `sum(f)` are valid and behave as expected?

Comment: Note that function overloading is also an option, but is arguably is even worse than templates, since you now need to overload for all combinations of numeric types.

Comment: Can't you just write `tsum(f);` instead of `tsum<int>(f);` thanks to template argument deduction?

Comment: @FredOverflow, Apparently so.... I actually never tried that.

Comment: Also, `std::accumulate(f.begin(), f.end(), 0.0);`

Comment: @FredOverflow: Tested with g++ 4.8.2, and yes, it works.

Comment: I guess that's the answer. I never heard of template argument deduction. By the way, I'm not actually trying to write a sum function. That was just a simple example for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Okay, then I don't have to point out that you should pass the vector by const reference if you're only going to read from it ;) `template<typename T> double tsum(const vector<T>& d)`

Comment: I'll edit the question so that nobody who tries to copy from this question will be misled into forgetting the &.

Comment: Well, except that with the `&` in the `double` case, the code will not compile when passed a `1`. Non-const lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues.

Comment: @merlin2011: Template argument deduction works with functions (not classes) by using pattern matching. If a function takes a `Dummy<T, U>` argument and you pass a `Dummy<int, double>` then there is a simple mapping `T -> int, U -> double` that the compiler is capable to do by itself. Bear in mind that there are sometimes non-deducible contexts (case where such inference is not possible), such as `foo(std::vector<T>::iterator)` because with template specializations there could be multiple values of `T` yielding the current type you pass.

Comment: @Angew I added the `const`.

Comment: @MatthieuM., thanks for the explanation of the caveat. I think for my purposes, being able to infer numeric types in function arguments is already highly useful.

Comment: @MatthieuM That is, not all functions are injective ;)

Comment: I'm not sure why people are trying to close this question. It is directly related to programming, even if it was a matter of not being aware of template argument deduction.

Comment: @merlin2011: I peeked at the reason, and the argument is that this question was solved in a manner that is unlikely to help future readers. I agree with the argument, but I personally am on the fence as to whether it's a good reason to close a question; in any case don't take it personally, it's just that some people are very zealous when it comes to cleaning up SO so that only questions that are *searchable* remain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't actually have to specify it (the compiler will "find it" through what's known as template argument deduction as @FredOverflow has mentioned in the comments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>                    
T tsum(std::vector<T> const& d)
{              
    T s = 0;                       
    for(auto x : d) { s += x; }
    return s;                           
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> f(1,5);
    tsum(f);

    std::vector<double> v(2, 6);
    tsum(v);

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e947cce9c06de71)

It should be noted that the standard library contains a function to do this already though: [accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: accumulate is really much better: suppose you have a user-defined allocator for your vector, or if you use a `std::list` or `std::array` as input range... ;-)

Comment: @TemplateRex `accumulate` can be tricky to use correctly, however.  You have to remember that the third argument defines the type of the accumulator; you can't just use `0` (unless you want everything converted to `int` during the accumulation).  And for user defined types, you have to remember that the expression is `acc = acc + *iter`, and not `acc += *iter`, which can have performance implications.

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, so a hybrid `tsum` that has the iterator interface but a range-for with the `+=` should be even better?

Comment: @JamesKanze Any particular reason `+` is used instead of `+=`?

Comment: @TemplateRex IMHO, yes.  I don't know the motivation for using `+` and not `+=`; you'd have to ask Stepanov that.

Comment: FWIW: I've been burned by the performance impact of `+`; at one time, I designed an "accumulator" which accumulates the SHA-1 hash for the string, so you're always adding `char`, but the accumulator required something like 48 bytes.  I implemented a special `operator+( char )` for it which had the semantics of `+=`, and which returned a special type; I then overrode the assignment operator of the accumulator for that special type, to do nothing.